# What endorsements benefit the tank's jet engine gun in Monday Night Combat?

Tags: xbox-360, monday-night-combat

When using a custom class you can choose various endorsements and I wanted to know which effect the tank's gun. I'm mainly wondering about the rate of fire and critical shot, but a list of those that do or do not would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh man, I love the tank I can't wait to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rate-of-fire endorsement definitely improves the Tank's Jet Gun.  This info comes straight from the developers:

http://www.mondaynightcombat.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=979

> Rate of Fire Endorsements (Total Recoil, Dr. Trigger, Itchy Finger)
>   affect most weapons. This includes:
>   Sword
>   Dagger
>   **Jet Gun**

You can see this most clearly when playing as the Tank and attacking Bullseye :)

Update: Critical shot also affects the Jet Gun:

http://www.mondaynightcombat.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=9869#p9869

> I thought I mentioned in my initial reply that Rate of Fire does affect Heal/Hurt gun, as 
>   well as Sword, Dagger and Jet Gun. 
>   Critical Shot affects all those things as well.

(note that he corrected himself later about RoF for the Heal/Hurt gun.  [This will be fixed in a later patch](http://www.uberent.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=2370)).